# Is declaring a PHP var valid with this syntax: &$var?

Tags: php, syntax

I'm upgrading old in-house PHP code for my company and I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```php
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    // do something
}
```

what's the meaning of `&$value` and can I safely assume this is a mistype?

Comment: Hint: From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): _In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not mistype. It is reference and it means to access the same variable content by different names. If you modify the value of `$value`, then you would also modify the original value inside `$array`.

You can read more about it at [References Explained, Php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)